# Why does my string cleanup function return the original value?

Tags: swift

I have made a func so that I easily can make all letters of a string lower case, while also removing all ! and spaces. I made this func (outside of viewdidload)

```
func cleanLink(linkName: String) -> String {
    linkName.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("!", withString: "")
 linkName.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
    linkName.lowercaseString

    return linkName

}
```

I then used these lines of codes

```
 var theLinkName = cleanLink("AB C!")


                print(theLinkName)
```

The problems is that this is just printing AB C! while I want it to print abc. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` returns a new string; it *does not* perform the replacement in place.

You need to use the return value of the function instead, like this:

```
func cleanLink(linkName: String) -> String {
    return linkName
        .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("!", withString: "")
        .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
        .lowercaseString
}
```

This "chains" the invocations of functions that produce new strings, and returns the final result of the replacement.